# How to protect code with a copyright licence from distributing/using elsewhere unless they buy it from me?

Tags: qt, software-distribution, rights, copyright-display

What I'll do in general :

- Program a software for a company
- Distributing the C++ and other source code to the company, they may arrange it as they want, reuse and edit it without warning me
- The source will contain some **.qss** files (Qt Style Sheet) that I want to protect

Why :

- Those .qss files I worked even before the company contacted me, I will include them in the pack of my work for their software they want I develop if they are ok with that, warning them that those are my products, I want to reserve to me the right to sell it for other software projects to other companies, or to sell it individually to anyone.

Another trick :

- I want the fact that the company can edit the .qss without my permission for their arrangment but only in the scope of the software I made for them. If they produce another Qt application, they can't just copy or reuse those .qss file. If they really want to do that, they'll have to contact me so I can sell those to them.

Upon you, what licence should I write in the first lines of those .qss file ?

Comment: I don't want to be "that guy", but to go 100% safe, you should consult a lawyer, no matter what someone will reply to your question.

Comment: @RichardSteinbrecht yes thank you for your advice, I just want to have some information so, if I consult a lawyer, I'll know some copyright example ect...
do you think this is too specific so I will use a custom copyright ?